# iPad App that loads website

Tags: ipad

This is a general question about iPad apps.

We have a conference coming up where we want to use some iPads and have an app that only displays our website.

So pretty much safari – though minus a browser/url bar and minus pinching / zoom so it functions like an app, without letting users navigate away to any other domains.

From what I understand there is no point trying to develop a site specific app that just displays a website because understandably, the apple store doesn't want that kind of stuff in it's store.

I just need something that acts like a shell.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, theres a thing called Guided Access, you can "crop" the area where they may not touch, anything in that zone wont work if tapped, and if you tap the home button they will be asked to enter a passcode.

To enable this:

Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Guided Access

1. Enable Guided Access
2. Set a passcode at Passcode Settings
3. Enable Accessibility Shortcut

Now go into Safari, press home button 3 times, start Guided Access, then draw a block on the address bar and the toolbar at the bottom. Tap Start to begin or Options in lower left corner for more options.

To exit, press home button 3 times and enter passcode.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebKit to build an iOS app sans the url/address bar. Learn more about WebKit and its counterparts [here](http://www.appcoda.com/webkit-framework-intro/).

One thing to note: a user of this app could simply tap a link on your site to exit the site and they would be elsewhere on the web...